# StreamPlot works slow with analitical functions

Tags: manipulate, vector, vector-calculus

I'm day to day user in Mathematica, that's I will be happy to any kind of help in code optimisation.

So, I try to plot gradient for beatings between two laser modes and plot intensity, phase and phase gradient distribution for different moments of time using "Manipulate" or "Animate" functions. When I plot only intensity (`Abs[]^2` and phase `Arg[]`) for analytical function it works slow, but at least it doesnt kick out the kernel. But if I add the phase gradient which I plot using `StreamPlot` function, It starts to work extremely slow and in 90% of cases it stacks or crashes the Mathematica. `Export` using `StreamPlot` also crashes the Mathematica. If I use the `VectorPlot` instead of `StreamPlot` it works more or less but slow. So how should I modify my code for better performance?

Complex functions:

```
    HLG1 = Omega01/Omega1*HermiteH[m1, Sqrt[2]*x/Omega1]*
    Exp[-x^2/Omega1^2]*HermiteH[n1, Sqrt[2]*y/Omega1]*
    Exp[-y^2/Omega1^2]*
    Exp[-I*(k1*z1 - (1 + m1 + n1)*Goui1 + k1 (x^2 + y^2)/2/R1)]
   
    HLG2 = Omega02/Omega2*HermiteH[m2, Sqrt[2]*x/Omega2]*
    Exp[-x^2/Omega2^2]*HermiteH[n2, Sqrt[2]*y/Omega2]*
    Exp[-y^2/Omega2^2]*
    Exp[-I*(k2*z2 - (1 + m2 + n2)*Goui2 + k2 (x^2 + y^2)/2/R2)]
```

Calculations for phase gradient:

```
    term1 = Conjugate[HLG1]*Grad[HLG1, {x, y}] + 
    Conjugate[HLG2]*Grad[HLG2, {x, y}]
    term2 = Conjugate[HLG1]*Grad[HLG2, {x, y}]
    term3 = Conjugate[HLG2]*Grad[HLG1, {x, y}]
```

Plot section:

```
Manipulate[{Show[
DensityPlot[
 Abs[Weight1*HLG1*E^(-I*2*Pi*Freq1*t) + 
    Weight2*I*HLG2*E^(-I*2*Pi*Freq2*t)]^2, {x, -c3, c3}, {y, -c3, 
  c3}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> StringForm["t=`1`", t], 
 PlotPoints -> 35, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 400}], 
StreamPlot[
 Im[term1 + term2*E^(-I*2*Pi*(Freq2 - Freq1)*t) + 
   term3*E^(-I*2*Pi*(Freq1 - Freq2)*t)], {x, -c3, c3}, {y, -c3, 
  c3}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", StreamScale -> Automatic, 
 VectorStyle -> White, VectorPoints -> Fine, StreamStyle -> White,
  MaxRecursion -> 0]], 
    DensityPlot[
Arg[Weight1*HLG1*E^(-I*2*Pi*Freq1*t) + 
  Weight2*I*HLG2*E^(-I*2*Pi*Freq2*t)], {x, -c3, c3}, {y, -c3, c3},
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 25, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None, 
ImageSize -> {400, 400}]}, {t, 0, 1/dw, 1/(dw*20)}];
```

Comment: Does your code work well when it is not inside `Manipulate`?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! You might want to try constructing all the graphics *first*, then using `Manipulate` to scan through the already-computed results. Though, you might need a lot of memory for that, and might run into memory issues. If you do, a workaround could be writing the graphics to `WXF` files in long-term memory, then using the `Manipulate` to read a particular one of them in—but i don't know, this might run into problems too.

Comment: Another option might be `Compile`-ing your numerical functions; that could speed things up.